# Javascript window.print in google chrome is stuck

Tags: javascript, printing

I tried to print a few elements using `window.open + window.print`.

Problem: When we close the print dialog using the browser "X" button, `window.print` keeps on running. No problem if I close the print dialog using print/cancel. See screenshot.

Here's my code:

```
  printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=' + screen.height + ', width=' + screen.width);
  printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Report</title>');
  printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  printWindow.document.write(gridData);
  printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  printWindow.document.close();
  printWindow.focus();
  printWindow.print();

  $("#printDiv .addedElements").remove(); //THIS WILL NEVER BE EXECUTED
  printWindow.close(); //THIS WILL NEVER BE EXECUTED
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome and is a major pain.

Comment: @Malk Thanks for the info but maybe there's a workaround for this one.

Comment: This might be fixed with version 36: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359627